# Evaluate a kronecker symbol sum: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\big(\frac n x\big)}n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\big(\frac xn\big)}n$

Tags: summation, closed-form, quadratic-residues, kronecker-symbol, alternating-expression

The [Kronecker Symbol $\left(\frac nm\right)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=kronecker+symbol) has a range of $\{-1,0,1\}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n=-\ln(2)$, so we combine to find the following with the using software. Also note the [**DirichletL function $\text L_{k,j}(s)$**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletL.html) from the link:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\left(\frac 2n\right)}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\left(\frac n2\right)}n=\text L_{8,2}(1)=\frac{\sinh^{-1}(1)}{\sqrt2}$$
which [seems true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Barcsinh%281%29%2Fsqrt+2-sum+jacobisymbol%28n%2C2%29%2Fn+from+n%3D1+to+9999%2C20%5D)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\left(\frac n3\right)}n=\text L_{3,2}(1)=\frac\pi{3\sqrt 3}$$

which [also seems true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bpi%2F%283sqrt%283%29%29-sum+jacobisymbol%28n%2C3%29%2Fn+from+n%3D1+to+9999%2C20%5D)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\left(\frac n4\right)}n, \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\left(\frac 4n\right)}n\text{ diverge}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\left(\frac n5\right)} n=\frac{\ln(\varphi+1)}{\sqrt5}$$

which [is probably correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bln%28goldenratio%2B1%29%2Fsqrt%285%29-sum+jacobisymbol%28n%2C5%29%2Fn+from+n%3D1+to+9999%2C20%5D). Note the [golden ratio](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=golden+ratio)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\left(\frac n6\right)} n\mathop=^?\frac\pi{\sqrt 6} $$

which [may be true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bpi%2Fsqrt%286%29-sum+jacobisymbol%28n%2C6%29%2Fn+from+n%3D1+to+9999%2C20%5D). Note the [golden ratio](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=golden+ratio). Are there any closed forms of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\left(\frac n x\right)}n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\left(\frac xn\right)}n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are values at $s = 1$ of the $L$ functions $L(\chi, s)$ attached to the quadratic characters $\chi(n) = \left(\frac m n\right)$.

Depending on the parity of $\chi$ (i.e. whether $\chi(-1)$ is equal to $1$ or $-1$, where we view $\chi$ as a Dirichlet character), they are either a product of $\pi$ with simple factors (evaluated as special values of [Hurwitz zeta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Negative_integers)) or something involving the $\log$ of a fundamental unit (the regulator) as given by [class number formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula#Dirichlet_class_number_formula).

I will not copy all the details here, but the above wiki pages should be good enough as starting points. Also these results should be available in many books on algebraic/analytic number theory, although they might not be listed together as the techniques are different for the two parities.

Comment: Thanks for the solid answer, but is it possible to write it in terms of the wolfram alpha function [DirichletL($k,j,s$)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletL.html)? It is partly defined as $\text L_{k,j}(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_{k,j}(n)}{n}$ where $k$ is modulo, index $j$, and $n$. Also, I am new to these functions. Do you know which values of $k$ or $j$ correspond to the two sums in the question?

Comment: I looked at their documentation: on [this page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletCharacter.html.en) they claim that "DirichletCharacter[k,j,n] picks a particular ordering for possible Dirichlet characters modulo k". I don't find anywhere what the "particular ordering" is, thus am not able to tell what $j$ is - you might have to do some test. The modulus $k$ should be $m$ or $4m$.

Comment: There is also a book *Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$* by David Cox, in which he talks about this kind of characters around Lemma 1.14.

Comment: @TymaGaidash The Dirichlet L function is a sum involving Dirichlet characters, so see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol#Connection_to_Dirichlet_characters.

Comment: @StevenClark Thanks for the link. From the article, there is a “quadratic law of reciprocity” relating $\left(\frac kn\right)$ and $\left(\frac nk\right)$.  How can one of the sums in the question be written in terms of the Dirichlet L function explicitly?

Comment: @TymaGaidash $L_{k,j}(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_{k,j}(n)}{n^s}$ so evaluating at $s=1$ leads to $L_{k,j}(1)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_{k,j}(n)}{n}$. Now for example $\chi_{5,3}(n)=\left(\frac{5}{n}\right)=\{1,-1,-1,1,0,...\}$ which repeats with period $5$, so $L_{5,3}(1)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_{5,3}(n)}{n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{5}{n}\right)}{n}=\frac{1}{5} \left(\sqrt{5} \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}+\frac{5}{8}\right)-\sqrt{5} \log \left(\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}\right)\right)$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Also $\left(\frac{5}{n}\right)=\left(\frac{n}{5}\right)$ so $L_{5,3}(1)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{n}{5}\right)}{n}=\frac{1}{5} \left(\sqrt{5} \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}+\frac{5}{8}\right)-\sqrt{5} \log \left(\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}\right)\right)\approx 0.430409$.

Comment: @StevenClark the “j” value is $2$, like in the question, or $3$, like in your comments. It looks like $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac n k\right)}n=L_{k,j}(1)$ or $L_{4k,j}(1)$. What is the value of $j$ here in terms of $k$? $j$ is an [“index”](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletL.html). Thanks.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Based on the Wikipedia article I linked above, if $a\neq (3 \bmod n)\land a\neq 0$, the map $\chi_{k,j}(n)=\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)$ corresponds to the modulus $k=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 4\, |a| & (a \bmod 4)=2 \\
 |a| & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.$. There are $\phi(k)$ Dirichlet characters for the modulus k, so $j$ is an index in the range $1\le j\le \phi(k)$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash You can explore Dirichlet characters on Wolfram alpha (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BTable%5BTable%5BDirichletCharacter%5Bk%2Cj%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Ck%7D%5D%2C%7Bj%2C1%2CEulerPhi%5Bk%5D%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C7%7D%5D ) and also LMFDB is a good resource (see https://www.lmfdb.org/Character/Dirichlet/?hst=List&modulus=5&search_type=List) but the two sites may use different indexing schemes with respect to $j$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NumberTheoreticCharacter.html and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletCharacter.html for more information on Wolfram's implementation of Dirichlet characters.

Comment: @TymaGaidash You can determine $k$ from $a$, but $j$ can vary. I'm not sure there's an algorithm for determining $j$, but you can determine $j$ by comparing the various Dirichlet characters with modulus $k$ to the Kronecker symbol $\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)$ which is what I did. You can explore Kronecker symbols and Jacobi Symbols on Wolfram alpha as well as Dirichlet characters (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BKroneckerSymbol%5Bn%2C5%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C5%7D%5D and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BJacobiSymbol%5Bn%2C5%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C5%7D%5D ).